# losing cookies when using header in php to redirect to another page

Tags: php, cookies

So, I want to create a cookie when the user logs in and then redirect the user to the another page. In the second page, I'm in need of the cookie from the first page. When I searched around upon how to redirect users to another page, everyone is telling us to use header(). However, I've got to know through researching that the header function will clear the cookies. I'm not sure if I'm right though. What should I do if it's true? Is there any way to redirect without losing the cookies.

```
setcookie("id", $id, 86400 * 30);

header("Location: index.php");
exit();
```

Comment: This should work. Make sure you don't have any other output before these calls -- check your log for "Headers already sent" warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Header function just set sends a RAW HTTP response back to the client.

The cookies are stored in the client's browser and the browser will send the cookies when the client tries to connect to the server again.

In short, **no** the header function does not "delete" the cookies.

However, if you are worried about the function (which you shouldn't be)

There are other work around using html/javascript.

HTML

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=index.php">
```

Javascript

```js
window.location.href = 'index.php';
// or
window.location.replace('index.php');
```

Comment: So what solution are you suggesting?

Comment: The code mentioned above, does not affect the cookies. It should work the way Shinji wants it to.

Comment: An answer should explain how to solve the problem. If you don't think there's a problem with the code, then it should be a comment.

Comment: Hi, I was able to find the answer to my question. The thing that made my cookie die before is not because of the header, but the expire date. I've set it as `86400 * 30` that basically says, it will expire right away. Just adding `time() ` to it made it worked. Thank you so much for explaining to me though :)

Comment: @Barmar: updated it with other workarounds. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Shinji Oh yea, missed that. It should be time() + (86400 * 30). You are correct!